# Sum values across worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which is a weekly report. By the end of the week it will contains eight worksheets, one for each day of the week and an 8th which reports the totals for the whole week.

Worksheets:

```
Mon, Tue, Wed, Thur, Fri, Sat, Sun, Week
```

Each worksheet has the same format copied from a template sheet.

For the sake of keeping things simple I've boiled this down to one cell B12.

`B12` on the worksheeet `"Week"` needs to equal:

```
=Mon!B12+Tue!B12+Wed!B12+Thur!B12+Fri!B12+Sat!B12+Sun!B12
```

I was going to use VBA to insert the above formula into Cell `B12` of the worksheet "Week" however I have a couple of issues:

1) If I run the report on Wednesday only `"Mon"` and `"Tue"` will exist. If I run the report on Saturday, `"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur"` and `"Fri"` will exist. This means I can't just insert the above formula into cell `B12` of "Week" because I get a `#REF!` error due to sheets that don't exist.

I need to add up all the `B12` values of any of the seven daily sheets but only if that sheet exists.

So if I run the report on Wednesday it equals:

```
=Mon!B12+Tue!B12
```

If I run the report on Saturday it equals:

```
=Mon!B12+Tue!B12+Wed!B12+Thur!B12+Fri!B12
```

2) This isn't applicable just to cell `B12` but to about 100 cells and they are not all in one range, they are spread out and some are merged cells etc. I want to apply a solution to many other cells without having to write out hundreds of if statements etc.

This is where I've got to so far but it doesn't work:

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim testVar As Double
Dim wsName As String
wsName = ws.Name
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case wsName
    Case "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
        testVar = testVar + Worksheets(wsName).Range("B12").Value
End Select
Next ws

Worksheets("Week").Range("B12").Value = testVar

End Sub
```

Comment: `wsName = ws.Name` needs to be inside the loop not before.

Comment: Why not just start with a blank sheet for each day, and paste the data into them as received. Then you just need: `=SUM('Mon:Sun'!B12)` as your formula.

Comment: @Scott Craner simple as that eh? :-) Thanks, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
Sub test()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim testVar As Double
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Selection

For Each c In rng

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
                testVar = testVar + ws.Range(c.Address).Value
        End Select
    Next ws

    Worksheets("Week").Range(c.Address).Value = testVar
    testVar = 0

Next c

End Sub
```

You should be able to select any range or individual cells in your 'Week' worksheet and hit the macro to get the sum of the matching cells in the daily worksheets where they exist.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you will have a file with certain number of sheets for each day, plus report sheet as the last sheet.
Then you can use n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count, which will be total number of sheets and get sum for sheets(1) to sheets(n-1).
Something like this:

```
x = 0
n = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
For i = 1 To n - 1
x = x + Sheets(i).Range("B12").Value
Next i
Sheets(n).Range("B12") = x
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to work but decided I want to use it as a function instead to minimize on the amount of code I need to write.

I've written the following as an example:

```
Function sumWeekly(cellToSum As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cumulativeVar As Double
Dim wsName As String
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
wsName = ws.Name
Select Case wsName
    Case "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
        cumulativeVar = cumulativeVar + Worksheets(wsName).Range(cellToSum.Column & cellToSum.Row).Value
End Select
Next ws

Worksheets("Week").Range(cellToSum.Column & cellToSum.Row).Value = cumulativeVar

End Function

Sub test()

Dim ppcsessions As Range

Set ppcsessions = Worksheets("Mon").Range("B12:B12")

sumWeekly (ppcsessions)

End Sub
```

But when I call "test" I get an Object Required! error?

Comment: This should be a new question not an answer to your original.

Comment: The quick answer to your question is `cellToSum.Column` returns a number and RANGE object uses a string.  You will need to use CELLS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code in a proper Function:

```
Function sumWeekly(cellToSum As String) As Double

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cumulativeVar As Double

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case ws.Name
    Case "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"
        cumulativeVar = cumulativeVar + Worksheets(ws.Name).Range(cellToSum).Value
End Select
Next ws

sumWeekly = cumulativeVar

End Function
```

It would then be called like this:

```
Sub test()

Dim ppcsessions() As String
Dim i As Long

'load this array with all the ranges desired.
ppcsessions = Array("B12", "I11", "G13")

For i = LBound(ppcseesions) To UBound(ppcsessions)
    Worksheets("WEEK").Range(ppcseesions(i)).Value = sumWeekly(ppcsessions(i))
Next i

End Sub
```